# Google Maps API is not marking restaurants, schools, etc on my map.

Tags: api, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

When using the **Google maps API** to display the map, restaurants, schools, airports, stores, etc. are not being marked as seen on **maps.google.com**.

How do you make the API mark these locations?

Comment: When I use the google maps API to display a location, the nearby restaurants,stores,schools etc. are not marked. I want these to be marked in my map. How to achieve this? I am using "address" as input parameter and "Geocoding" to display the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use the [Places library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html), but it won't be as easy as you'd like.  There are currently some 126 different place types you'd have to consider.